# How to jquery autocomplete json results?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two problems with the code anexed:

The first is, the search results in json only appear when I delete the text input, not as I type ... like I need to be. The second is, when I click on one of the results show it, I need the text go to the value of the input text.

How i can do this?

pastebin with [the code](http://pastebin.com/rd7K8aGn):

pastebin with [json example](http://pastebin.com/P2Wuyysm):

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you post an example about your json data? I could help you if I know the json structure.

Comment: Of course, i edited the description (sou brasileiro também).

Comment: I saw comments written in Portuguese ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with Autocomplete [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), it doesn't works with json data, only with arrays.

Try somethink like this, should work.

```
var arr = ['project1', 'another project', 'more one project'];

     $("#project").autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: arr,
       focus: function( event, ui ) {
         $("#project").val( ui.item.label );
         return false;
       }
     });
```

To hide results when erase field you should set minLengh <= 1 like this:

```
$project.autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: projects,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      $project.val( ui.item.label );
      return false;
    }
  });
```

If you wanna search data in your back end I think you should consider use the option to filter data as query string, check this doc section:

> String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can
>   be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The
>   Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.

Comment: I think that this is not the problem, because i have an example with a static json and works perfectly. And even with this code above, the autocomplete works when i delete the value of the text, not while i'm typing.

Comment: Now I'm confused, can you show your example with static json working on a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I saw now, project is an array ;)
Its look like working fine here, what the mater with your code?
Remember that autocomplete's input is debounced and you need stop writing to show results.

Comment: This is exactly the json returned in data.php?query=, when i type something, and when i erase the input the results apear!
    [
{
"pic": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12750120_598731973612154_857884034_a.jpg",
"username": "@claudiaalende"
},
{
"pic": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12716459_1065423093480213_516150090_a.jpg",
"username": "@divulgacao16_"
},
{
"username": "#claudiaalende",
"pic": "hashtag.png"
},
{
"username": "#claudiaalende",
"pic": "hashtag.png"
}
]

Comment: Doens't work with the dynamic search... i think the problem is the $.getJSON don't have the results in real time...

Comment: why are you using "$("#project").keypress(function() {" this? JQueryUI no need you handle keypress events.

Comment: Finally i get it, the problem was the include of javascript on the <head>, when i move to the bottom of <body>, works fine. Thank you.